# Rails mailer RestClient::BadRequest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to insert mailing function in my website, 
but it keeps getting error and I couldn't find any answer buy googling

I'm not an expert, so even if this is an elementary level question please understand, and if any information is needed please let me know!

Here's my code.

**index.html.erb**

```
<a href="/home/email_test">test</a>
```

**home_controller.rb**

```
def email_test
    @user = User.last
    UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver_now

    redirect_to :back
end
```

**environments/development.rb**
(I tried quoting and unquoting port number 587, and changing autentication :plain and :login)

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
    port:                 587,
    domain:               'gmail.com',
    user_name:            'my_mail_id@gmail.com',
    password:             'my_mail_password',
    authentication:       :plain,
    enable_starttls_auto: true
}
```

**mailers/user_mailer.rb**

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
    default from: "my_mail_id@gmail.com"

    def welcome_email(user)
        @user = user
        mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Welcome to My Awesome Site')
    end
end
```

And this is my error code in console

```
Started GET "/home/email_test" for 121.140.234.142 at 2017-04-06 04:17:09 +0000
Cannot render console from 121.140.234.142! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by HomeController#email_test as HTML
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."inactive" = 'f' AND "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."inactive" = 'f'  ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  Rendered user_mailer/welcome_email.html.erb within layouts/mailer (0.1ms)
  Rendered user_mailer/welcome_email.text.erb within layouts/mailer (0.1ms)

UserMailer#welcome_email: processed outbound mail in 11.2ms

Sent mail to user_mail_id@user_mail.com (1123.5ms)
Date: Thu, 06 Apr 2017 04:17:09 +0000
From: my_mail_id@gmail.com
To: user_mail_id@user_mail.com
Message-ID: <58e5c145eb445_8eb3fc731278548409bb@~~.mail>
Subject: Welcome to My Awesome Site
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="--==_mimepart_58e5c145ea640_8eb3fc73127854840896";
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit


----==_mimepart_58e5c145ea640_8eb3fc73127854840896
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

CuyasOyDgeyaseuLmCwgZXhhbXBsZS5jb23sl5Ag7Ja07ISc7Jik7IS47JqU
Lgo9PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09
PT09PQogCmV4YW1wbGUuY29t7JeQIOqwgOyehe2VmOyFqOyKteuLiOuLpC4g
64u57Iug7J2YIHVzZXJuYW1l7J2AIOyasOyDgeyaseyeheuLiOuLpC4KIArs
nbQg7IKs7J207Yq47JeQIOuhnOq3uOyduO2VmOq4sCDsnITtlbTshJzripQg
aHR0cDovL2xhbmdkeS5uZXQvdXNlcnMvc2lnbl9pbuydhCDtgbTrpq3tlbTs
o7zshLjsmpQuCiAK6rCA7J6F7ZW07KO87IWU7IScIOqwkOyCrO2VqeuLiOuL
pC4K

----==_mimepart_58e5c145ea640_8eb3fc73127854840896
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
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----==_mimepart_58e5c145ea640_8eb3fc73127854840896--

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1150ms (ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)

RestClient::BadRequest (400 Bad Request):
  app/controllers/home_controller.rb:137:in `email_test'


  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (5.7ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.7ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.6ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (30.0ms)
```

Please let me know any idea!

Comment: The error from your log makes it look you're not running a you're server locally on localhost (127.0.0.1). Is that the error you're having trouble with?

Comment: It seems so! So I solved it with third party mailing server. Thanks @ellitt you gave me a hint!